# BotFramework call Telegram method (getChatAdministrators)

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, telegram-bot, channel

How i can call a Telegram method (getChatAdministrators) from BotFramework

I have tried this code but response is empty

```cs
        turnContext.Activity.ChannelData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            method = "getChatAdministrators",
            parameters = new
            {
                chat_id = chat.Id,
            }
        });

        var response = await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity);
```

Comment: Did my answer help? Do you have any further questions? If it helped, can you upvote/mark as answer to help other people in the future?

Comment: @DrewMarsh Thanks to answer but not help. new Activity() - getting an error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'". With turnContext.Activity.AsMessageActivity() and ChannelData - getting an one value "Id". In result i have uses a TelegramBotClient()

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` property of the `ITurnContext` represents the *incoming* activity for the current turn, so if you're trying to send a new activity, you don't want to use/mutate that instance, you want to create a new one.

I haven't personally done exactly what you're asking with Telegram, but this is the general approach you should be using:

```cs
var response = await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity
{
    ChannelData = new 
    {
       method = "getChatAdministrators",
       parameters = new 
       {
           chat_id = chat.Id,
       },    
    },
});
```

> NOTE: there's no reason to manually JSON serialize anything either, just use anonymous types if you want to (you could also create your own strongly typed classes marked up with JSON.NET serialization attributes) and they will serialize just fine.  IMHO, a good channel integration should supply a NuGet package with channel specific types/extensions in it, but since V4 is relatively new right now there aren't that many extensions yet.